# Where does Submit button get wired up to in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project.

In order to login, I created a window, and then put a partialview in the window and it shows up just fine.  The question is, how do I then capture the result in the controller so I can actually do the backend login?

This is the _LoginPartial based off of the sample MVC 4 project in VS;

```
<section id="loginForm">
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</fieldset>
```

}

In other words, where does the submit go to?  I want it to call AccountController.Login(model, returnUrl) but I don't get how the wiring works.

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<section id="loginForm">

@* Change the Html.BeginForm as below *@
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</fieldset>
}
```

Then in your controller, make sure you have an ActionMethod that has the `[HttpPost]` attribute and accepts your model, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model) 
{
    // process login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `actionName/controllerName` parameter to `Html.BeginForm`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
```

Use [FormExtensions.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492692%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)